# Page Verify- CHECKSUM or TORN PAGE

Tags: sql-server, database

**Dear All,** 
While reading on the net i have found that it's always better to have CEHCKSUM option instead of TORN_PAGE_DETECTION or NONE under the page_verify_option_desc. I have found few of our databases using the TORN_PAGE_DETECTION and NONE. Now if i want to change these settings, do you advise me to consult the application vendor firs or as a DBA i can just go ahead and do it without referring back to them. 
any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option specifies how SQL Server monitors **physical** corruption of database pages. As such, unless your software accesses database files directly, without Database Engine providing logical interface, you don't have to consult any vendor - no business software interacts with databases on this level.

The `CHECKSUM` mode has only been added in SQL Server 2005, so you have a good chance encountering other values in databases upgraded from SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions. Of course, it is better to switch them to the latest (and the best) verification mode, but make sure you perform proper integrity checks, [dbcc checkdb()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql) at the very least.

Comment: Thank you very much Roger. There is one small part which i didnt really understand "As such, unless your software accesses database files directly, without Database Engine providing logical interface". How they will access the files directly? We have applications and that applications connected to the database, so thats mean they are connected through logical interface. So in this case i can go ahead and apply the changes without referring back to them (vendors) right?

Comment: @BuRaiR, absolutely. The only kind of software that has "direct" access to database files are usually 3rd party management / maintenance tools,  like various transaction log explorers, maybe something similar as well. Everything else cannot be affected by this database setting.

Comment: Thank you very much Roger Wolf. You have answered my questions. I will start changing the Page Verify as soon as possible and run the dbcc checkdb after that. Thanks alot.